# Did Lord Ram command Laxman to have Sita executed? (As opposed to being taken to Valmiki's hermitage)

Tags: ramayana

Paraphrasing a reddit post, the poster claimed to have read a certain Kannada translation of the Valmiki Ramayana by an individual named N Ranganatha Sharma, where Ram asked Laxman to have Sita executed. Is that canonical?

Answer (score 0):

No. Rama clearly tell Lakshmana to leave Sita near Valmiki Ashram -

> "**On the further side of the Ganges, the magnanimous Valmiki has his
> hermitage of celestial aspect situated by the Tamasa;** **it** **is in
> a solitary spot that you should leave her**, O You who art the Joy of
> the House of Raghu. Go quickly, O Saumitri, and carry out my behest."

Chapter 45, Uttara Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.

2. Lakshmana tells Sita the same thing -

> "**I am to leave you in the vicinity of the sacred hermitages**. The
> king has commanded me to do so on the pretext of satisfying your
> desire. The ascetics’ retreats on the banks of the Jahnavi are sacred
> and enchanting, do not give way to grief, O Lovely One. The foremost
> of Rishis, the supremely illustrious Sage Valmiki was a great friend
> of your sire, King Dasaratha. Taking refuge under the shadow of the
> feet of that magnanimous One and living in chastity, be happy, O
> Daughter of Janaka."

Chapter 47, Uttara Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: Thanks for replying, what do you think is the context on that translation which the redditor claimed to have read?

Comment: @Lurkinghindu - I haven't seen any such translation. Did the redditor provide any actual source for the claim ?

Comment: just the author's name

Comment: @Lurkinghindu - The reddior could be lying or could be mistaken. Or it could be some other version of Ramayana.